# fetching results based on Year ,month date hour in SQL query for both MySQL and Oracle DB

Tags: mysql, database, oracle

I have following data in the table stats

```
+--------------+------------+------+----------+---------------+---------------+--------
| stat_id | day        | hour | type     | success_count | failure_count | quarter 
+--------------+------------+------+----------+---------------+---------------+--------
|    1    | 2020-01-07 | 10   |       99 |             5 |             3 |       1
     2    | 2020-01-07 | 10   |       99 |             2 |             2 |       1       
|    3    | 2020-02-08 | 15   |       99 |             3 |             3 |       2
|    4    | 2021-03-07 | 18   |       99 |             1 |             2 |       1       
|    5    | 2021-04-07 | 20   |       99 |             5 |             3 |       1
```

I want to prepare 4 queries from which I can fetch the entries based on YEAR/MONTH/DAY/HOUR.

I want to fetch the entries YEAR wise: (Its working)

```
select substr(day,1,4) as "Year", SUM(success_count) as "TOTAL SUCCESS",SUM(failure_count) as "TOTAL FAILED",SUM(success_count)+SUM(failure_count) as "TOTAL REQ" FROM statistics WHERE type=99 GROUP BY Year ORDER BY Year"
```

After executing this I will be getting below result:

```
+-------+-------------------+------------------+------------+
| year | TOTAL SUCCESS | TOTAL FAILED | TOTAL REGISTER REQ |
+-------+-------------------+------------------+------------+
| 2020  |            10 |            8 |             18
| 2021  |            6 |            5 |             11
+-------+-------------------+------------------+------------+
```

I want to do this for month ,day as well as hour, Can anybody help me with this

like for month I want result like this,

```
+-------+-------------------+------------------+------------+
| month    | TOTAL SUCCESS |TOTAL FAILED | TOTAL REGISTER REQ |
+-------+-------------------+------------------+------------+
| 2020-01  |            7 |            5 |             12
| 2020-02  |            3 |            3 |             6
| 2021-03  |            1 |            2 |             3
| 2021-07  |            5 |            3 |             8
+-------+-------------------+------------------+------------+
```

Similarly for DAY:(This one I will get by default as I am storing based on DAY in table so it just need select *)

```
+-------+-------------------+------------------+------------+
| DAY        | TOTAL SUCCESS |TOTAL FAILED | TOTAL REGISTER REQ |
+-------+-------------------+------------------+------------+
| 2020-01-07  |            5 |            3 |             12
| 2020-01-07  |            2 |            2 |             6
| 2020-02-08  |            3 |            3 |             3
| 2021-03-07  |            1 |            2 |             8
  2021-04-07  |            5 |            3 |             8
+-------+-------------------+------------------+------------+
```

HOUR DETAILS:-- (on 7th Jan 2020 , in 10th hour there were 2 requests, its not like how many requests were made on that perticular hour on any date, its like sublinks, i.e It start with year on clicking on that perticular year it display the monthly wise ,in there date wise inside that hour wise ex- 2020->10(Dec)->15(date)-> 3rd(hour)) like nested links

```
  +-------+-------------------+------------------+------------+
    | HOUR | TOTAL SUCCESS |TOTAL FAILED | TOTAL REGISTER REQ |
    +-------+-------------------+------------------+------------+
    | 10  |            7 |            5 |             12
    | 15  |            3 |            3 |             6
    | 18  |            1 |            2 |             3
    | 20  |            5 |            3 |             8
    +-------+-------------------+------------------+------------+
```

Adding Table Definition for MySQL

```
+----------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| stat_id        | bigint(10) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| day            | char(10)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| hour           | char(2)    | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| type           | int(2)     | YES  | MUL | 0       |                |
| success_count  | bigint(10) | YES  |     | 0       |                |
| failure_count  | bigint(10) | YES  |     | 0       |                ||
| quarter        | char(2)    | YES  |     | 1       |                |
+----------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code.

Comment: You cannot have 1 query for mysql and oracle the syntax is different.and please add table definition are dates character or date datatypes?

Comment: Hi @P.Salmon I have updated the question added the Table Definition,Oracle table not yet designed currently implementing considering MySQL db

Comment: " I have updated the question added the Table Definition"  I don't see it.  All I see is a display of the data.  We need to see the actual CREATE TABLE, so that we know the data types.

Comment: If your query for YEAR is working,
did you try for MONTH


    select substr(day,1,7) as "YearMonth", SUM(success_count) as "TOTAL SUCCESS",SUM(failure_count) as "TOTAL FAILED",SUM(success_count)+SUM(failure_count) as "TOTAL REQ" FROM statistics WHERE type=99 GROUP BY YearMonth ORDER BY YearMonth